# Get unique files from s3 bucket

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am worknig on .net c# project. My code is fetching files from s3 bucket. In s3 bucket there are some duplicate files but their names are different. I want to fetch only unique files from s3 bucket.
I am using this query to fetch all files from s3 bucket

```
ListObjectsV2Request listRequest = new ListObjectsV2Request { BucketName = awsBucketName, Prefix = fullPath };
var listResult = await client.ListObjectsV2Async(listRequest);
var obj = listResult.S3Objects.Where(x => x.Key.EndsWith(".pdf") && x.Size > 0)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastModified)
```

How to get files with unique content to avoid duplicates?

Should I just read all files 1 by 1 and remove duplicate ones?
Or is there any easy way to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Check the etag, as long as the files are not encrypted with different KMS keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the ETag which files that have the same content will have the same Etag and grouping them by ETag will group all the duplicates so you can choose only one of them

```
ListObjectsV2Request listRequest = new ListObjectsV2Request { BucketName = awsBucketName, Prefix = fullPath };
var listResult = await client.ListObjectsV2Async(listRequest);
var obj = listResult.S3Objects.Where(x => x.Key.EndsWith(".pdf") && x.Size > 0)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastModified).GroupBy(x => x.ETag)
                    .Select(x => x.First())
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: While this will work for many use cases, it should be noted, large files can be the same but have differing ETags due to how they're calculated.

Comment: @AnonCoward theoretically yes, practically no. Also this has nothing to do with the file size but simply how any hash function works, it always has potential hash collisions.

Comment: @luk2302 I'm not talking about hash collisions.  The formula used to calculate the ETag is in part based off the size of chunks for multipart uploads.  If you use a different size, either because of different SDK choices, or manually changing it, then the ETag will differ.  It will also likely differ if the object is copied from S3 to S3, as that can use a different size internally.  This is something that can happen practically.